# Can you open Access 2007 database using Delphi 2010 on a computer without MS Office?

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2007

Can you open Access 2007 database using Delphi 2010 on a computer that doesn't has MS Access instaled?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by open, if you mean use the ACE drivers, then http://www.microsoft.com/en-IE/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Comment: @Remou To use data from access database in delphi application on a computer without access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can open an ADO connection to an MS Access database and access the data in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Use a TADOConnection object and set its ConnectionString to the result of this function:

```
FUNCTION AccessConnStr(CONST FileName : STRING) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    {$IFDEF CPUX64 }
      Result:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source='+FileName
    {$ELSE }
      Result:='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.0;Data Source='+FileName
    {$ENDIF }
  END;
```

Just give the file name to the function, and it'll return the connection string needed to access the file. This works at least with Access MDB files - haven't tried anything else...

If you do not know how to use TADOConnection to access databases, search the net. That subject is too broad for a Q&A site like StackOverflow.

I have not had a machine (XP and newer) that have failed to access the .MDB file using this connection string - whether they had MS Office installed or not, but of course can't vouch for every single PC in the world :-).

Comment: Be carefull that this IFDEF will not work if the target machine is different (CPUX64 or not) than the compiling machine!

Comment: @birger Could you elaborate on that? I haven't had any problems with using this (the 32-bit version for many years, the 64-bit version only recently).

Comment: The IFDEX works only when you compile the app. So when you compile on a X64 machine you hard-code that connection string into the application. When you run the app on another machine that is not X64 you will still get the hard-coded X64 connection string.
But even then: I dont think the choice of JET or ACE should depend on X64 but on the availability of either on the target machine.

Comment: If you run a program compiled with CPUX64 on a machine that is not X64, then the program simply won't run (it's a Windows 64-bit executable), so there's no problem there. And I have never seen a machine capable of running a 32-bit executable (ie. both Win32 and Win64) that didn't have the JET OLE provider already installed. Yes - it would be better to test for the presence of the provider, but as I haven't had the need for it (I have never failed to get the provider I asked for, although I haven't run 64-bit for so long), I haven't investigated how to detect the presence of the provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to download this:
Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime
From:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.